# Para que serve Validation_data na função fit() do Keras

Tags: python, keras

Já pesquisei, mas não consegui compreender muito bem qual o benefício de utilizar o validation_data. E só é usado para as amostras de testes?

```
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `validation_data` só é usado para as amostras de teste, ele não é usado para treinar o modelo. Ou seja, não é feito o backpropagation com estes dados. Sua principal função é ajudar a encontrar o ponto em que seu modelo está treinado no ponto ideal, sem underfit (poderia ter aprendido mais) ou overfit (aprendeu mais do que devia).

Na prática, seja seu modelo definido como:

`model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001), metrics=['accuracy'])`

Os dados de teste são utilizados para calcular, no final de cada época, o erro e a acurácia do seu modelo.

Guardando estes valores para cada época:

```
history = model.fit( x = X_train, y = y_train,
    validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
    [...]
)
```

A variável `history.history` guarda os valores da perda e acurácia de cada época:

```
>>> history.history.keys()
    dict_keys(['loss', 'accuracy', 'val_loss', 'val_accuracy'])
```

E é possível visualizar estes dados da seguinte forma:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='loss')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='val_loss')

plt.title("Loss")
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Ou trocar o `'loss'` e `'val_loss'` por `'accuracy'` e `'val_accuracy'`.

Por meio destes gráficos, conseguimos decidir qual a melhor quantidade de épocas para treinar o modelo, vendo quando a o valor da perda nos dados de validação (`val_loss`) começa a crescer e quando a acurácia nos dados de validação (`val_acc`) começam a decrescer.

Comment: O certo nao seria o val_loss cada vez menor e o val_acc cada vez maior?

Comment: No começo do treino, sim. Depois de várias épocas, o modelo fica enviesado para os dados de treino e, por consequência, começa a errar os de validação.